# wanted to access a variable from main class to other class...

Tags: android

my program is as follow:

```
public class HelloGridViewActivity extends Activity {

    public int pos;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                pos = position;
                Toast.makeText(HelloGridViewActivity.this, "" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent secondActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), seconactivity.class);
                startActivity(secondActivity);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my main class file and my other java file is as follow

```
public class seconactivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        HelloGridViewActivity position1 = new HelloGridViewActivity();
        int p = position1.pos;
        if (p == 0) {
            setContentView(R.layout.ashtavinayak);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.ayadhya);
        }
    }
}
```

nw i wanted to access pos variable defined in the main class to the seconactivity class..can any1 tell me how can i do this???

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to pass it in the intent, either as data or as an extra (look at `Intent.setData()` and `Intent.putExtra`.

In the second activity, you can call `getIntent()`, and then read its data and extras.

Comment: thnks ayublin..but i got 1 more way
just in the main class
declare a variable as 

    public static int pos;

and in the seconactivity class use it as follow


    int p = HelloGridViewActivity.pos;   
    if(p == 0)    
    {    
    setContentView(R.layout.ashtavinayak);    
    }    
    else     
    {     
    setContentView(R.layout.ayadhya);    
    }
    }

Comment: @Parth Dani I also prefer your way but its very risky in big projects. :) wot EboMike said should be the best practice